# HTML CSS element postitioning to one side

Tags: html, css

I am creating a food-based website and i want the twitter feed to be on the right hand side, but stretched to the length of the site.

**HTML**

```
<div id="left">
<p style="font-family:Oswald; color:white; font-size:50">Welcome to fish and dips!</p>
<p style="font-family:Lato;font-size:20;color:white;">sample text</p>
</div>

<div id="right">
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-dnt="true" href="https://twitter.com/FishandDips" data-widget-id="625342290215763968">Tweets by @FishandDips</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</div> <!-- this is just a custom twitter feed generated by twitter -->
```

**CSS**

```
.left {
float: left;
}

.right {
float: right;
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: 'but stretched to the length of the site' - you mean to the right of the page and the full height of the page right?

Comment: @smoggers correct sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have id attributes in your div elements but you are selecting by class in your css.

According to your needs, you can change your html to something like this:

```
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

**or** your css to something like this:

```
#left {
    float: left;
}

#right {
    float: right;
}
```

Take a look here: [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)

Comment: @carriotshare one solution **or** the other, you applied both :)

Comment: but now it isnt large enough, how would the width be enlarged?

Comment: @carriotshare check width and max-width properties of #twitter-widget-0 iframe

Answer (score 0):

If you did not define width for your divs it will take width of container and float and right will have not effect when there is big data .They will occupy full width,From left to right and from right to left

```
#left {
float: left;
width://
}

#right {
float: right;
width://
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.left {
float: left;
}

.right {
float: right;
}
```

CSS selector for Class id "." not "#"